What is the intended way of passing c++ Views and Ranges to functions?
Usage Scenario
I would like to do roughly this:

Write a function foo( Container<std::string> container) that accepts any iterable container as long as it contains strings
Call foo and give it the values I get from filtering a std::vector<string> like this:

   std::vector<std::string> myList = { "a", "b" };
   auto filteredList = myList | std::ranges::views::filter([](std::string elem) {
       return elem == "a";
   });
   foo(filteredList)

Attempt
I come from other languages, where there is the concept of iterable interfaces. The Q&A
"What is the correct approach to passing a std::ranges::view type object to a class?" explains parts for this:

how we can create a templated function that can accept a view as a parameter
how to use requires to ensure the element type must be std::string

We get something like this:
template<std::ranges::view ViewOfDetections> requires std::same_as<std::ranges::range_value_t<ViewOfDetections>, std::string>
void foo (ViewOfDetections container){
  // implementation must be here.
}


However, this seems very clunky:

The use of templates means that we can not separate the declaration from the code. All of it must be together in the header file (unless I misunderstood this. But it does not seem to work to split it up because what comes after the template part is not a class template.)

The declaration type is not very readable. Other languages have some interface type that you can specify instead.


Question
It very much feels like I fundamentally misunderstood something or missed a basic std feature.
What is the correct, established, elegant, maintainable, readable way to do write a function that can operate on any iterable container - i.e. on a view or a range - of a specific element type?

Another way of doing this is outlined in "Declare template function to accept any container but only one contained type" but it comes with the same drawbacks and even worse readability:
    // template: a Container that takes variadic arguments, and the said arguments (types).
    // Whatever we pass in will be fed our required type std::string as first type template argument.
    // The other arguments are figured out by the compiler, if they are required.
    // This declaration in itself would also accept anything else that is templated, not just containers.
    // But that would then lead to a derived template resolution failure.
    template< template < class ... > typename Container, class ... Args>
    void foo(Container<std::string, Args...> container)
    {
        // do something with the container elements
    }


Related Links
For the benefit of future readers, this Q&A "Range Concept for a specific type" might also be of interest. It discusses same_as vs convertible_to and range_value_t vs range_reference_t.

Instead of passing a container why not passing the container's iterator?

@Dialecticus What does it improve?

AFAIK you wont be able to get away from using a template.  Once thing you can do is create a concept that requires a range of string and then the function simplifies to void foo(StringRange auto range) { do_stuff_with_range; }

@Dialecticus that would work, but then what is the whole point of views and ranges? It sounds to me like they are supposed to replace old-style function calls where one passes .begin() and .end()

@lucidbrot If you accept iterators, you still need a template, and still need clunky concepts to constrain the iterator (or if you settle for just (T begin, T end), you might as well do const T &container without any concepts).

The price of compiletime polymorphism is publishing source as text; the catch is optimized build. Using ranges view as the comstraint on input is the smart choice with cleaner syntax for template programing. Do not fall in the trap of iterators; you'll need extreme care with bounds whenever you deal with one. template template is not the goto option if there is any other. You can use shortcut template function syntax: void foo(std::ranges::view auto rng) requires std::convertible_to<range_value_t<decltype(rng)>, std::string>; template constraints are just compile-time perdicates in C++.

Then you call: foo(my_rng | std::views::all);. all safely makes an instant-use reference/view out of the input range. The verbosity of views::all clearly shows the intent to pass-by-ref at call site, and using ranges::view at declaration/definition site prevents extra copies by discarding pass-by-value at compile time.

You can also build your own constraint: template<typename str_rng> concept view_of_strings = std::ranges::view<str_rng> and convertible_to<range_value_t<rng_str>, std::string>;. Then use it to constrain your own functions: foo(view_of_strings auto rng);

My personal way would be two templates:
template <typename Iterator>
void foo(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
    requires(std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(*begin)>, std::string>)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(*begin)>, std::string>);
    // ...
}

template <typename Container>
void foo(Container /*const*/& c)
//                   ^ const, if foo is not intended to modify the container!
{
    foo(std::begin(c), std::end(c));
}

The static_assert might be an alternative if you want to keep the function declaration more compact, I'd rather prefer the requires clause instead, though, as it shows right at the declaration what actually is expected.

The second overload should use a const or forwarding reference. And you can keep only the second overload and pass ranges::subrange when you want two raw iterators.

@HolyBlackCat Well, depends, it's not actually clear if foo is intended to modify the container... And I wouldn't drop the other overload, it's more convenient (for the user) to have the iterator variant available than having to create yet another object from the iterators.

Thanks for this answer! I realized now that this is suitable for one of my use-cases. There, my foo is private anyway, so does not have to be implemented in the header as nobody outside the .cpp file is instantiating the template anyway. For that, I find this answer works and is readable.

Would there be any advantage to specifying template <std::ranges::input_range Container> instead? Or is anything that would do already implied here?

@lucidbrot That would make explicit already in the declaration what kind of type actually is expected – and maybe bring a slight advantage in respect to compilation time as the concept can be checked before any instantiation has taken place while my variant would fail only when duck-typing fails (maybe after quite a bunch of unrelated code has already been compiled).

@lucidbrot Going over question and answer again it appears to me that the iterator variant might not be of much worth for you; you can transform the container variant to operate on the container directly, the std::string requirement can be transformed accordingly: requires(std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(*begin(std::declval<Container>()))>, std::string>) (see godbolt).

Firstly, if you use a template, the concept should be std::ranges::input_range (or some other ??_range, not view). This allows you to directly accept containers.
Second - yes, this is clunky, and only makes sense for generic algorithms (like those in <algorithm>). Higher-level code should probably accept std::span<const T>, and it's the job of the caller to convert their views into a contiguous container.
You could come up with a type-erased class (think std::function for ranges) that lets you accept any range without templating the function, but this would have performance overhead (compared to, say, span).

First off, thanks! Those are very helpful pieces of information. Does this mean in practise I would have to perform a copy of the view first, to get contiguous memory for the span?

@lucidbrot If you use a span, yes.

Just to duble-check my assumptions: is it (still) true that generally I'd want to have my code split up into declaration (header files) and cpp files with the implementation? Because any kind of template kind of destroys this. Or does modern cpp just embrace header-only code despite the implication that any code change will require a full recompile?

@lucidbrot There's no single authority on "modern C++", but yes, generally you still want a separate .cpp file to have decend build times, that's why I'm suggesting span and a non-template function.
